# Is 'en' often used as a handle for something used earlier?

Tags: traduction, pronoms, en

#### An example sentence

Z a pris la serviette et en a frotté la chevelure de L, avant de la nouer en turban autour de sa tête.
(from book: Dans le café de la jeunesse perdue, author: Patrick Modiano, p. 28)

#### My translation

Z took the towel and rubbed the hair of L dry with it, before tying it into a turban around her head.

#### My thoughts

- The first 'en' refers to the towel. (This usage of 'en' is hard for me to learn.)
- The second 'en' just means 'in/into'. (This usage of 'en' is easier for me to learn.)

#### Question

In order to get more familiar with the first use of 'en' :
Can I say that 'en' is often used as a handle(/referral) for something mentioned earlier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*En* is a pronoun in this case.  It replaces nouns used with the preposition *de*, often a partitive (le partitif) pronoun.  That can be a noun that takes the indefinite article de, du, de la, de l', and des.  In general, when you see a form of *de*, it gets replaced with the pronoun *en*.

Here, the pronoun *en* goes with the verb *frotter + de* to replace de la serviette because you can use *frotter quelque chose ***de****, to cover something by rubbing it with something.

[Le Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/frotter) gives the definition:

> Frotter qqch. de, avec…, enduire par frottement.

From this definition, we see that the pronoun *en* is used with *frotter de* when the direct object means a person or part of a person:

> [Le compl. d'obj. dir. désigne une pers. ou une partie d'une pers.] Le divin vieillard trempe un peu de coton dans une huile consacrée; il en frotte les tempes d'Atala (CHATEAUBR., Génie, t. 2, 1803, p. 256) [TLFi](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?12;s=2155854150;r=1;nat=;sol=1;)

So it applies (literally) to L's hair being toweled off.

Effectively your translation of "with it" works.  I might say "Z took the towel and used it to rub L's hair before wrapping it in a turban around her head."

More information on the pronoun *en* [here](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3513).

The second *en* is a preposition, which like you said can be translated as in, into, or as or like (sorry I didn't see it in the question at first, thank you user LPH).  It is not related to the pronoun.

Comment: So, I could replace it like that: *_ ... et il a frotté la chevelure de L de la serviette,... _*

Comment: Your answer was very helpful in many ways, I appreciate it very much.

Comment: La première partie de la réponse est fausse.

Comment: La deuxième partie de la réponse est également fausse.

Comment: Il n'y a rien d'enduit par frottement dans cette phrase; le sens de frotter n'est pas celui d'enduire dans ce contexte. Cette définition n'est pas la bonne.

Comment: @Fólkvangr En n'est pas le complément du verbe frotter dans ce cas ?

Comment: l y aurait une erreur ou un néologisme dans la phrase « Z a pris la serviette et en a frotté la chevelure …». What's meant: Z rubbed the hair with the towel…». Le problème est que « frotter qqc de qqc » n'est pas défini dans le TLFi, où on ne trouve que le verbe pronominal « se frotter de/avec » voulant dire « s'essuyer, se laver ». Ce n'est pas « en » qu'il faudrait mais « avec » : Z a pris la serviette, avec laquelle il a frotté la chevelure…».

Comment: @colorblind I would say « et il a frotté le chevelure de Z avec la serviette. » comme LPH vient de dire.

Comment: Pour ne pas répéter « serviette » vous pouvez écrire « et  avec il a frotté le chevelure de L …».

Comment: Dans le premier cas, le pronom *en* représente l'action en cours mais avec un focus particulier (que chacun peut imaginer).

Comment: On peut changer la phrase comme cela : ***Z** a frotté la chevelure avec la serviette, puis **l**' a nouée autour de sa tête.*

Comment: Dit autrement, l'action se déroule en trois temps : 1) On prend la serviette 2) On essuie avec la serviette 3) On enroule la serviette autour de la tête.

Comment: @livresque: De par sa position, le mot *en* (ici c'est un pronom) a une fonction de sujet pas celle d'un complément.

Comment: @livresque: L'analyse grammaticale de la phrase ne correspond pas à votre propos. En outre, ne pas confondre **catégorie grammaticale** avec **fonction** : en peut être *pronom*, *préposition* ou *adverbe* et avoir plusieurs fonctions, comme *COD*, *COI*, *complément du nom, complément cc. de lieu, de temps, de manière*.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple, the pronoun **en** replaces a *groupe nominal* preceded by *de* unless it is a person, e.g *Il parle souvent de ses aventures* becomes *Il en parle souvent*, that's the first *en*. The second **en** is a *préposition*, it can usually be substituted by **comme** or **like** in English: ".... avant de la nouer en turban" which is equivalent to ".... avant de la nouer comme un turban".

Comment: And for a person? Lets say: Il parle souvent de son frère. Is there a replacement?

Comment: You can say:Il en parle souvent but it is highly inadvisable doing so, the better formulation is:Il parle souvent de lui.